# Do static local variables in C functions affect execution speed?

Tags: c, optimization, static

I understand that it's best not to use register variables in C, unless you have special reason to think you're making a better decision than a modern compiler can.

Since local static variables stick around between calls to a function, does it make any sense to use those when execution speed matters?

I'm working on a 6502 emulator (just for fun and learning). Most of the emulated operations don't need local variables at all, but a few do. I've pasted an example below. Basically, I'm wondering if there'd be any benefit in declaring those variables as static. Not to preserve their values between function calls, but to prevent their storage space being reallocated each time. Is this another case where it's best to just leave it to the compiler?

```
static void
op_asl_zero_page_x (CPU *cpu)
{
    unsigned int result;
    Word addr;
    Byte b;

    addr = zero_page_addr_XX (cpu, cpu->x);
    b = bus_read (cpu->bus, addr);

    /* Copy highest bit to carry */
    cpu->status[CPU_STATUS_C] = ((b & 0x80) != 0);

    result = (unsigned int)b << 1;
    bus_store (cpu->bus, addr, result);
    cpu_set_N_Z (cpu, result);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: But `static` and non static variables have different semantics? Their lifetimes are different. Not exactly interchangeable.

Comment: It's another case of *premature optimization*. You only optimize after you *identified* (without doubt) a performance problem. That said, I don't think it matters for the CPU by how many bytes the stackpointer changes, so, no, local variables (in typical stack-based implementations) aren't slower.

Comment: Making the variables static would make the code harder to read, more difficult to debug and would create a very interesting source of bugs. I very much doubt the potential speed improvements (if any!) could offset these downsides.

Comment: Discussing optimization without a specific system in mind is rather pointless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a typical `x86` system, when you enter a function, there is no additional computational cost in reserving space for local variables.

Entering a function implies moving the stack pointer. Moving it 8 bytes is not cheaper than moving it 16 bytes. It's the same sequence of assembly instructions.

You *are* using up more *memory*, in the stack, but unless you plan on doing some seriously deep recursion, you shouldn't worry about that. All of this assuming that your compiler actually decides to use the stack to store the content of those variables (they might be mapped to registers).

So, in terms of computation, there's no cost. In terms of memory, very little cost.

Comment: Thanks, slezica and others. I'm pretty vague on exactly how compilers do things, but this is the kind of project that'll help me learn. Your answer clarifies things :)

Comment: Adding to that: `static` storage duration means the variable lives for the full execution time of the program, so the compiler would need to store/access the variable in memory if it can't optimize its usage away. Without `static`, a register could be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think declaring function as static just tells compiler this function can only be used in current file(xxx.o)  and doesn't have other benefits.

Comment: Not correct, the `static` storage class specifies linkage *and* storage duration, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44614284/2371524). Plus OP was talking about variables, not the function itself.